# Why I can not start my application.war Spring boot maven in Websphre 9?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, webxr, websphere-9

I have error when I strat my application.war, API Rest, spring boot, maven in websphere 9 server that is the error :

```
     FFDC Exception:com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning SourceId:com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl ProbeId:297 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@2e3bbf6e

com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: null

            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:433)

            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)

            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1249)

            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1591)

            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:720)

            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1162)

            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:801)

            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2325)

            at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5568)

            at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5694)

            at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)

            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2330)

            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)

            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)

            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)

            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)

            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)

            at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)

            at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)

Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: null

            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:914)

            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)

            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)

            ... 18 more

Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: null

            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:186)

            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)

            ... 20 more

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

            at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:145)

            at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:134)

            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getJspApplicationContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:267)

            at com.ibm.ws.cdi.web.impl.AbstractServletInitializer.onStartup(AbstractServletInitializer.java:104)

            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:653)

            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:437)

            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)

            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)

            ... 21 more

Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Unable to find ExpressionFactory of type: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more

            at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:181)

            at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:105)

            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.<clinit>(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:58)

            ... 27 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more

            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:610)

            at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:273)

            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:942)

            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:887)

            at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:150)

            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:870)

            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:67)

            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:63)

            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:630)

            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:870)

            at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:630)

            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:870)

            at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:174)

            ... 29 more
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>MyApplication</name>
    <description>MyApplication API</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>...
```

Do you have any idea of this error?

knowing that my application only contains the backend controller Rest and I excluded Tomcat.

I thought about creating in my application an empty web.xml to resolve this error, do you have any suggestions to unblock me?

I wait your response and thank you in advance.